# How do I install the latest version of VLC media player?

Tags: updates, vlc

The version supplied is significantly out of date, to the point where I faced issues with specific codecs relying on a newer version. I would prefer an official build or repository.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Install from a Repository

You can install the latest *supported* version from the [Official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily). This has the added benefit of being an official build and distribution channel, maintained by VLC themselves.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Am I the only one who using the above commands still receive version 2.2.7 Umbrella ?

Comment: It appears that 2.2.2 is the latest version built by Videolan Stable Daily PPA for Xenial at this time.

Comment: Yes, It looks like you are right.. But if I use in Ubuntu Xenial the gnome-software application, there is an option to download version 3.0.1 which is more stable and videos play and navigate much more smoothly than any 2.2.x version.. And I have decided that probably it is the new one stable, but.. looks like I am wrong. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 4):

The official PPA from Videolan does not contain all the libraries needed to run VLC like HEVC support. This [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) is specifically for users looking for media updates. Its contains the latest version of VLC and other popular video players.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

Comment: I used ppa:mc3man/bionic-media for Bionic Beaver 18.04.