# Adding support for the “hevc” format to VLC without using ppa

Tags: codec, vlc, ppa

I know that I can add support with this code:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

But I do try to avoid using ppa. is there another way to install the plugin without using ppa?
(I have access to git)

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade to VLC 2.2.x or higher to get HEVC/H.265 support.To upgrade to latest version please refer

[how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-vlc-media-player](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-vlc-media-player/2404#2404)

(here you need to install `gstreamer1.0-libde265` separately)

---

To add support to `hevc` with out PPA please refer [here](http://pastebin.com/TP6Rczur),I am just copy & pasting commands here.

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install git -y
 cd /tmp
 git clone https://github.com/mmstick/ubuntu-10bit-encoding-tools
 cd ubuntu*
 ./install.sh
```

<sub>source [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)</sub>